# Conversion from string to double - Possibility and errors

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy

I am aware that the string 2.34 would never be equal to the double 2.34. No matter what library or algorithm you tried (lexical_cast,atof). Also 2.3400 can not be represented as double type. Instead it will be equal to 2.3399999999999999 . A little background I am working on an application that passes of values to an external application using its api. Think of it as some sort of a trading application. The user can pass values using the applications api or the user can pass value by using the application directly.Now when the user uses the application directly and the user types in 2.34 the value is processed as 2.34 however when I use the API which requires double as a parameter I pass 2.34 and it passes of as 2.3399999999999999 which is not acceptable. My question is how would the application be handling this and is there a way to store 2.34000.. in a double so that I could pass it to an API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pass decimal values through an API which takes `double` but you need to get the exact values, there isn't much of a problem: As long as you don't use more than `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10` digits, you can recover the original decimal *value* although not necessarily the same *representation* (trailing fractional zeros will be lost). To do so, you need to convert the original decimal string into the closest representation as `double` and later use a suitable algorithm to restore the best decimal representation again. The parsing and formatting functions from the C and C++ standard libraries will do that correctly for you.

Note that you shouldn't try to do any arithmetic on the `double` values when you want to restore the original decimal values: the result of `double` arithmetic will use binary rounding and the values won't be the closest decimal values. However, as long as you only transfer the `double` values, there is no problem.

Comment: the closest double type value from the string "2.34" I get is 2.399999 . Could you explain the next step I should use that would help me pass a double of 2.34 to the API ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: I thought you understood that it is impossible to represent many fractional decimal values exactly using a binary floating piint like `double`! It is **not** a problem of the libraries but of the representation: a`double` is represented as (-1)<sup>_sign_</> * _significand_ * 2<sup>_exponent_<sup> where _sign_ is 0 or 1, _significand_ is a positive integer, and _exponent_ is an integer. However, if both the caller and callee of an API understand that the `double` used represent decimal values, the processing can still be made to be correct!

Answer (score 0):

The one way to work around floating point precision issues is using a well made fraction class. You may code one for yourself or use the ones provided by common math libraries. Such classes will represent your `2.34` as `234/100` internally, which will lead higher amount of memory consumption compared to a single float.

Comment: Any suggestion of such a library. Apprently `double j = float(234)/float(100);` obviously still has the same answer

Comment: I googled and these are the results: http://code.google.com/p/cppfrac/  and  http://individual.utoronto.ca/rafatrashid/Projects/2009/FracLibDoc/index.html

Comment: There is also boost's rational numbers but i tend to avoid boost for such little cases.

Comment: @Rajeshwar: You might want to consider decimal floating point numbers. Although I'm not aware of a publicly available C++ library there is [decNumber](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decnumber.html) which is a C library. The [C++ Decimal TR](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) specifies how a C++ version could look like and there is a [paper](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3407.html) improving this interface using C++11 features.

Comment: This is not the only way to work around floating-point precision issues; the first sentence is incorrect to say so.

Comment: Eric Even if I have a fraction class the API requires a decimal how do I go about converting a fraction to a decimal. I tried both the links posted by @diegoperini. I still dont see how fractions would give  me a double value that I need to send such as 2.340000 ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar: I do not recommend using this answer for your task.

Comment: I am still looking at other options didnt know it could get this hard

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention *"trading application"* I will conclude that the numbers represent currencies. If that is the case you are probably dealing with a fixed number of fractional digits as well. In that case you can scale your floating point numbers by multiplying them by `10 ^ number_of_fractional_digits`, essentially making them integer values. Floating point numbers can accurately store integer values (as long as they do not exceed the floating point type's range).

Another possibility - if the assumptions above are correct - would be to use [Binary-coded decimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal).

Comment: So if I have an int of a double (i.e for 2.34) it will be 234. How is that any good to pass to an API that requires a double ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar 234 can be exactly represented as a floating point value, in other words, when converting 234 to 234.0 there is no rounding error.